# Best search intelligent extension

Tags: magento2

Anyone can suggest to me the best search intelligent extension for Magento 2.

Answer (score 0):

> **Try this**

https://www.mageworx.com/magento-2-search-autocomplete-free.html

It's free and provides a good user interface and also provides good features.

Comment: Click here to download https://drive.google.com/file/d/16MPW600VzvY8ubomyOMTFgy3OJMf8W2O/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you. I'm still looking for a search module that can show the result with the closest product if customers miss-spelled the name